# How can i put validation on the below fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I am trying to apply validation on below Fields PLease Help . Normal Validation like check whether empty or not and if Empty show error on fields . How can i do that ?

   My HTML Code

   Form Name

   ```
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1"
                        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
                        data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                       <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                           <div class="modal-content" style="padding:20px;">
                                 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" role="form">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="frmName">Form Name *</label>
                                         <input id="frmName" type="text"
                                                  name="frmName"
                                                  class="form-control input-lg"
                                                  placeholder="Please enter your form name *"
                                                  required="required"
                                                  data-error="form name is required."
                                                  ></input> 
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                               </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="txtProductName" class="control-label">Select Product : </label>
                                   <select required="required" data-error="form name is required." style="width: 260px;height :35px; font-size: 15px;" class="form-control" id="op1">
                                       <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                                   </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                  </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="frmdesc">Form Description *</label>

                                           <input id="frmdesc" type="text" name="name"
                                                  class="form-control"
                                                  placeholder="Please enter your form Desc *"
                                                  required="required"
                                                  data-error="full name is required."></input>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                               </div>

                               <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button type="button" class="js-save-form fb-button" onclick="checkValidation();"
                                           data-dismiss="modal">Proceed</button>
                               </div>
                                       </form> 
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
   ```

Comment: <button id="btnFormNameModal" style="display:none;"
                            class="js-save-form fb-button" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Form Name</button>

Comment: You forgot put your javascript snippet

Comment: On the above button i am getting the pop up .

Comment: function checkValidation(){
                
                 var Name = document.getElementById('frmName').value;
                  
                  if (Name != ""){
                 $('#contact-form').formValidation('resetForm', true);
             }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will useful.

**jQuery:**

```
function checkValidation()
{
    $('.required-fields').each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).addClass('.alertClass');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('.alertClass');
        }
    });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.alertClass{border-color: indianred;}
```

Comment: Please add jsfiddle for it.

Comment: add `required-fields` class for every required fields.

Comment: what exactly i am looking for is i want to validate the form inside bootstrap modal and only after successfull validation the bootstrap modal should closed and if any fields is empty it should show error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and check it.

```
//Check your Jquery and jquery.validate.min.js

//add script
        <script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#contact-form").validate();
        });
function validon() {
$("#contact-form").valid()
//or if ($("#contact-form").valid()) {}else{}
}
        </script>


    //html
             <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" role="form">
            <input type="text"  id="txtTest" name="Test" required />
            <input type="button" id="btnvalid" value="valid" onclick="validon();" />
            </form>
```

Comment: what exactly i am looking for is i want to validate the form inside bootstrap modal and only after successfull validation the bootstrap modal should closed and if any fields is empty it should show error.